# How to get permalink of post based on post name?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, permalinks, get-posts

Hi I want post permalink like events/post-name not events/?post_type=45

I am using get_permalink(20).

Comment: What code are you using to register the CPT? What are your permalink settings?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your permalink structure from **Plain** to **Post Name**.

For that, Go to Settings > Permalinks

[image]